# Android In-App Billing (Subscription) testing

Tags: android, xamarin.android, in-app-purchase, subscription

I added subscription in my Android app. Now I'm testing it.

1. I added test account in Goggle Play Developer Console.
2. I buy a subscription on devices(with test account). I get PurchaseToken.
   PurchaseState = PaymentPending.
3. When I check this token on my server  I get PurchaseState = PaymentPending.

   Is it normal? With true purchase PurchaseState = PaymentRecived or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscriptions have a Trial Period, clients are not charged until this period expires.

But I think that to know if the client has already payed has a minor importance.

What really matters is to know if she/he have an active subscription and you will know it by calling IInAppBillingService.getPurchases, if he don't finally pay the item it will be erased in the list of purchases.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you. that's what I need